# How to call a webservice method from an html page [javascript] with out refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-services

I have a `webservice` which will return a value. Here my requirement is, I need to call that `webservice` from an `index.html` page, that page have an html submit button. On that button click I am calling a `JavaScript.` From there I want to call the web method. how can I achieve this.

My webservice is `"localhost/ws/service.asmx";` and  web method is `HelloWorld`

```
 <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn_submit" onclick ="return fun()">

 function fun() {


    // here  I want to call the "helloworld" method.
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use jQuery for performin POST or GET request from your html page like this :

```
function fun() 
{
   var data="hello";
   $.get("http://localhost/ws/service.asmx/HelloWord", function(response) {
        data = response;
   }).error(function(){
  alert("Sorry could not proceed");
});

   return data;
}
```

OR :

```
function fun() 
{
  var data="hello";
  $.post('http://localhost/ws/service.asmx/HelloWord',{},function(response) 
  {     data = response;
  }).error(function(){
  alert("Sorry could not proceed");
});

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Hi Aditya , thank you!. Here My webservice is "http://localhost/ws/service.asmx" and my webmethod is HelloWorld.

So how can I give that

function fun() 
{
   $.get("http://localhost/ws/service.asmx", function(Helloworld) {
        //alert(response);
   });

   return true
}

is it ????

Comment: sorry to say.. it is not .. first one is not throwing any error but it is not returning the output string. second one says undefined object data_value

Comment: Thank you for your reply , but Sorry it is again returning "Undefind"

Comment: the webservice is returning a string "Hello world".

Comment: alert(response) and check what's being returned to your page?

Comment: 'response' is undefined

Comment: Then you are not returning anything from server side ? check once if you are using `context.Response.Write("Hello World");` to send response..

Comment: [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld() {

       

        return "Hello World";
    }



this is what my method..  simple one

Comment: `public void HelloWord(HttpContext context)
  {
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write("Hello world");
  }` Try this

Comment: I think the webservice call itself is not happening , I was trying to create the log file over the webservice call . but it is not generating any files.

Comment: that too giving me undefined

Comment: Check the updated answer, if there is an error in the request

Comment: it is returning 
"Sorry could not proceed"

Comment: `onclick ="fun();"` , try this

Comment: same result "Sorry could not proceed"

Comment: I think the webservice call itself is not happening , I was trying to create the log file over the webservice call . but it is not generating any files

Comment: if am directly accessing this , it is giving the error "Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/HelloWord'."

Comment: but if I am accessing the localhost/ws/service.asmx service and then after invoking the method from the browser  it is working fine.

Comment: Try setting the URL to your method as the url for GET request, simple

Comment: sorry i dint get that

Comment: The URL that u access your method from your browser, set that url for the GET Request?

Comment: Your functions will always return "hello", as they end instantly and before the callback functions are executed.

Answer (score 7):

You can send [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request to a webservice

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "WebServiceURL",
            data: "", //ur data to be sent to server
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
               alert(data);
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
               alert(x.responseText +"  " +x.status);
            }
        });
```